# Want to create CIRCLES with half area in negative margin

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Below is the Image. I want to create circle the same way as in the image.
which WIDGET i should use to create circle as given in Image?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4eBN.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The image looks like it's a splash screen. If it is the case, use this instruction: [Adding a splash screen to your mobile app](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen).

If you certainly need a *widget* looking like these circles, I'd recommend using [CustomPaint](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html). It provides you with a powerful Canvas API allowing you to draw basically anything in any way you want.

Don't forget to wrap it into ClipRect widget or otherwise the circles might overflow causing rendering errors.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own CustomPaint and draw the circles as you want

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Material(child: MyWidget())
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint( //This accepts a custompaint in the painter parameter
      painter: CircleBackground(),
      size: MediaQuery.of(context).size,
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12),
          child: Text('Let\'s achieve your targets together!', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black))
        )
      )
    );
  }
}


//This is where you draw your customPaint
class CircleBackground extends CustomPainter {

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint outerCircle = Paint()..color = Colors.grey[700]..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    Paint middleCircle = Paint()..color = Colors.yellow..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    Paint innerCirle = Paint()..color = Colors.orange..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    canvas
      ..drawColor(Colors.white, BlendMode.screen) //the color of the background
      ..drawCircle(Offset(size.width/8, 40), size.width * 1.1, outerCircle)
      ..drawCircle(Offset(size.width/8, 40), size.width * 0.85, middleCircle)
      ..drawCircle(Offset(size.width/8, 40), size.width / 2, innerCirle);
    /*
    You can test different Offset to move the center of the circle, 
    drawCircle receives the offset of the center, the radius as a double and 
    the paint object where you can define color, stroke line, etc
    */
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CircleBackground oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. You just made it look so easy.